# How can we know the width and height of string?

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to create a button exactly the same size as the string for this i want the width and height of the string.

Comment: Do you know the font-metrics the string will be rendered in? Because otherwise you have no chance.

Comment: i have font_type and pixel size of the string.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To manually get the size of a string, you need to use the [QFontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html) class. This can be manually used like this:

```
QFont font("times", 24);
QFontMetrics fm(font);
int pixelsWide = fm.width("What's the width of this text?");
int pixelsHigh = fm.height();
```

If you want to calculate it for the font used in a given widget (which you may not know), then instead of constructing the fontmetrics, get it from the widget:

```
QFontMetrics fm(button->fontMetrics());
int pixelsWide = fm.width("What's the width of this text?");
int pixelsHigh = fm.height();
```

Then you can resize the widget to exactly this value.

Comment: For **multiline** measurement you'll need an overload of `QFontMetrics::boundingRect` which accepts a flags parameter.

Comment: In qT 5, there is no `width()` method. The documentation's example from https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html uses `horizontalAdvance()` instead.