# QML - wrapped text right alignment

Tags: text, alignment, qml, word-wrap

I want to set the right alignment for the wrapped text. If I set:

```
wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
text: "text\ntext"
```

I will get wrapped text but aligned to right "before" wrapping. Sth like:

```
    text    |
    text    |
```

instead of

```
        text|
        text|
```

Do I have to set additional params etc.?

Comment: Your code does exactly what it should to do - aligns text to right. Probably you have some error in another part of the code. Please post all relevant code so it will be possible to test. Also screenshot  would be a nice addition.

Comment: Looks like it's related to the QT version - 5.2.1 doesn't support it correctly.

Comment: I can confirm that ^. Do you want to answer your question so others know that it's solved?

Comment: Problem solved - we need to use newer QT version (or check text width - sth like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872462/how-can-we-know-the-width-and-height-of-string )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - we need to use newer QT version (5.2.1 was bugged) or check text width - sth like [Measuring text width in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337523/measuring-text-width-in-qt)